# Show $\frac{\pi^2}{6}\sqrt{ab+\sqrt{ab+2\sqrt{ab+3\sqrt{\cdots}}}}>4$ by hand .

Tags: solution-verification, improper-integrals, gamma-function, nested-radicals

Problem :

Show that if :

$$a=\int_{0}^{1}x!dx,b=\int_{0}^{\infty}1/\Gamma(x)dx,x!=\Gamma(x+1)$$

Then we have :

$$S=\frac{\pi^2}{6}\sqrt{ab+\sqrt{ab+2\sqrt{ab+3\sqrt{\cdots}}}}=4.0054\cdots>4$$

There many things related to the Basel constant as the probability to get a prime number for example .

The Fransen Robinson constant have nice integral represntation with exponential notably .

Note that the problem is similar to nested radicals due to Ramanujan .

I hope to see nice proof which could use simple bound or Cauchy-Schwarz inequality .

---

---

Dig the problem :

Using [The Infinitely Nested Radicals Problem and Ramanujan's wondrous formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4049946/the-infinitely-nested-radicals-problem-and-ramanujans-wondrous-formula) :

**Cheating** one radicals we have for :

$$2(2u+v)=(u+v)^2-ab$$

We get $u\simeq -1.795,v\simeq 2.795$

Introducing :

$$f(x)=ux+v$$

Setting :

$$uX+v=0$$

We have :

$$ |S6/\pi^2-ab|\simeq X/10$$

Already it can be done by hand if we have a good approximation for the integrals .

A relatively good approximation is :

$$\int_{0}^{1}1/576(-x^5+x^3+6x^2-6x+24)^2-x!dx>0$$

Nota bene :

As in my comment we can reach an equality for some constant $m,x$ :

$$\sqrt{ab+\sqrt{ab+2\sqrt{ab+3\sqrt{\cdots}}}}\left(1+1/2^2+1/3^2+\cdots+1/m^2+1/(m+1-x)^2+1/(m+1+x)^2\right)=4$$

For a bit of geometry see also Fuss's theorem for bicentric quadrilateral .

> > Question :

How to show it without the help of any numerical assistance so by hand ?

Comment: Long time no see ! Nice problem but may I use my abacus ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Yeah nice problem found relatively quickly after a dream . If we use $\sum_{1}^{436} 1/n² =1.6426431$ and multiply by $2.4351$ we get a nice approximation or an almost integer .For your abacus (old computer?) you need some time and time after Stephen Hawking is numerics so we can try the old method pencil and paper ;-) .

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Can you make an answer with numerical checking to enlight the problem ?

Comment: Now, prove that, if $ab=2.577369193391029779713573708923493043415319293014$ the result is larger than $4$ (in fact, it is $4+2.773\times 10^{-49}$

Comment: I forgot to precise : not exactly mental calculation

Comment: Do you know that this is a very interesting function ?

Answer (score 2):

It works

I used $a$ and $b$ with $500$ decimal places.

As a function of $n$, the results are
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 3.3713015211722886250 \\
 2 & 3.6786518328632658644 \\
 3 & 3.8317135361506168988 \\
 4 & 3.9125545019488574270 \\
 5 & 3.9559753173774284169 \\
 6 & 3.9792859467378086387 \\
 7 & 3.9917168350426439386 \\
 8 & 3.9982924950986951448 \\
 9 & 4.0017446141959247234 \\
 10 & 4.0035452069065250960 \\
 20 & 4.0054686797256613817 \\
 30 & 4.0054709810658212318 \\
 40 & 4.0054709835714249571 \\
 50 & 4.0054709835740579318 \\
 60 & 4.0054709835740606477 \\
 70 & 4.0054709835740606505 \\
 80 & 4.0054709835740606505 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

For $n=167$, fifty exact significant figures.

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$ab = \frac {57}{22}-5.047\times 10^{-5} $$ and $S$ is an increasing function of $n$.

For $n=9$, $S=4.00177$.